# mysql structure for including two references in one field

Tags: mysql

This seems like it should be easy, but I'm banging my head against the wall.  I'm creating a site in php/mysql where, when a user pulls up a day of the week, it will list assignments given to them grouped by chunks of time, e.g., 8-11, 11-14, etc.

I have a table set up like this, where the fields are intended to reference another table containing tasks.  Each integer corresponds to a unique task in the tasks table.

```
       8-11   11-14  14-17  17-20   20-23 
Mon     1       3      4      1   2
Tues   1,3      4      5      6   7 
Wed    1,2,3    5      4      8   9
```

As you can see, some days have repeating tasks at different times (e.g., on Monday, task 1 is performed during the 8-11 and 17-20 slot).  And most baffling for me is how to set up the table or join multiple tables to address time slots with multiple tasks, e.g., the Wed 8-11 shift has three tasks, 1, 2, and 3.

My question:  can you suggest table structure(s) that would be optimal for this, and an example query to retrieve the tasks for a given day?  THANK YOU.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

** EDIT ** Here's what I'm trying to ask: looking at Wed 8-10, how can I pull the three tasks from the task table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2130b/8

```
CREATE TABLE work_periods (work_period_id int unsigned, weekday int unsigned, description varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE tasks (task_id int unsigned, description varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE work_period_task_assignments (work_period_id int unsigned, task_id int unsigned);
INSERT INTO work_periods VALUES (1, 1, 'Mon 8-11'), (2, 1, 'Mon 11-14'), (3, 1, 'Mon 14-17');
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (1, 'Drink Coffee'), (2, 'Make Toast'), (3, 'Do Work');
INSERT INTO work_period_task_assignments VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2,3), (3,3);

SELECT p.description as period, t.description as task FROM work_periods p
INNER JOIN work_period_task_assignments wpta
ON wpta.work_period_id = p.work_period_id 
INNER JOIN tasks t
ON wpta.task_id = t.task_id 
WHERE p.weekday = 1;
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius.  Works perfectly.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
period (id, desc, start_hour, end_hour), e.g. "8-11"
task (id, desc), e.g. "Task 1")
period_task (period_id, task_id)
```

So you'd have three rows in period_task for task 1.

Comment: Thank you, Alain.  I didn't explain the question well, but it was answered above.

Answer (score 0):

For a structure, you can use a single assignments table:

```
CREATE TABLE assignments (
  assignment_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user int,
  dt datetime,
  assignment_name varchar(50))
```

You can then use `CASE` to group the number of assignments. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
SELECT timeRange, COUNT(*) AS assignments
FROM
    (SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN HOUR(dt) BETWEEN 8 AND 11 THEN '8-11'
            WHEN HOUR(dt) BETWEEN 11 AND 14 THEN '11-14'
            WHEN HOUR(dt) BETWEEN 14 AND 17 THEN '14-17'
            WHEN HOUR(dt) BETWEEN 17 AND 20 THEN '17-20'
            WHEN HOUR(dt) BETWEEN 20 AND 23 THEN '10-23'
        END AS timeRange
    FROM assignments) t
GROUP BY t.timeRange
```

You would add criteria to filter by `user` and `date` range as needed.

Comment: I like that - thank you.  I wasn't clear in my question, though and I'm still confused as to how to pull in multiple tasks from one field...any help?

Comment: @user1596165 What do you mean by 'pull in multiple tasks from one field'? Are you saying that in each field (ie. `assignments`) you have multiple tasks?

Comment: Njk, yes.  For example, during the 8-10 shift on Wednesday (keeping with the original table, above) workers have to perform tasks 1, 2, and 3 which are all different.  In the "tasks" table the different tasks are listed with a primary key.  This would be pretty simple if there weren't these multiple tasks/time slot.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1596165 The way you are explaining sounds as a non-normalized structure. Each assignment should have its own row.

Comment: @user1596165 Show us a sample of your data from your tasks table

Comment: Njk, thank you very much for your help.  I think the problem was that I couldn't explain what I was trying to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear you can't have 2 references in one field so I use a table to hold the cross-referencing ... namely daily_tasks, you can insert as many items as you want there for each timeslot of a day, the only limitation being you can't have the same task twice in a single timeslot, but even that can be removed if you remove the primary key declaration

```
create table task(
   id tinyint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
   name text not null
) engine InnoDB;

create table timeslot(
   id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
   date date not null,
   time tinyint unsigned not null
) engine InnoDB;

create table daily_tasks(
   timeslot int unsigned not null,
   task tinyint unsigned not null,
   foreign key(timeslot) references timeslot(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
   foreign key(task) references task(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
   primary key(timeslot,task)
) engine InnoDB;
```

insert some sample data

```
insert into task (name) values ('wake up'), ('wash'), ('eat'), ('drink'), ('go to work'), ('do some work');
insert into timeslot (date, time) values ('2012-09-18', 8), ('2012-09-18', 11), ('2012-09-18', 14), ('2012-09-18', 17), ('2012-09-18', 20);
insert into daily_tasks values (1, 1), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,6), (3,6), (4,3), (4,4), (4,2);
```

to select all tasks for a day

```
select timeslot.time, task.name from timeslot join daily_tasks on daily_tasks.timeslot = timeslot.id join task on task.id = daily_tasks.task where timeslot.date = '2012-09-18' order by timeslot.time asc;
```

query results

```
+------+--------------+
| time | name         |
+------+--------------+
|    8 | wake up      |
|    8 | eat          |
|    8 | drink        |
|    8 | go to work   |
|   11 | do some work |
|   14 | do some work |
|   17 | wash         |
|   17 | eat          |
|   17 | drink        |
+------+--------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

alternative query with concatenated tasks

```
select timeslot.time, group_concat(task.name) from timeslot join daily_tasks on daily_tasks.timeslot = timeslot.id join task on task.id = daily_tasks.task where timeslot.date = '2012-09-18' group by timeslot.time asc;
```

resulting in

```
+------+------------------------------+
| time | group_concat(task.name)      |
+------+------------------------------+
|    8 | wake up,eat,drink,go to work |
|   11 | do some work                 |
|   14 | do some work                 |
|   17 | wash,eat,drink               |
+------+------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

since apparently all intervals are 3 hours long I didn't include an endtime for tasks since that can be calculated by adding 3 to time